# Using multipleSQL select statements with different conditions

Tags: sql

I am working on generating a report that will output different statistics for each employee. My boss would like to see how long it takes to ship orders. We are an online retailer dealing with orders from a single item to hundreds or thousands. Orders over 12 items are treated as "bulk" orders, anything else is treated as a "small" order. All of the data being used for calculations is coming from the same table, but the limitations on which data to pull is different.

These are the requirements for each piece of data he wants collected.

```
SELECT AVG(bulkFTS) as bulkMODFTS
FROM cartHead
WHERE  rateFactor <> -1 AND rateFactor <> 0 AND bulkStartDate <> NULL
```

---

```
SELECT count(idOrder) as totalOrders
FROM cartHead
WHERE rateFactor <> -1
```

---

```
SELECT count(idOrder) as overFTS
FROM cartHead
WHERE smallFTS > 27 AND rateFactor <> -1 AND rateFactor <> 0 AND bulkGlassCount = ''
```

---

```
SELECT round(sum(rateFactor),1) as totalFactors
FROM cartHead
WHERE rateFactor <> -1 AND rateFactor <> 0
```

---

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(FTStime),2) as avgFTS
FROM cartHead
WHERE rateFactor <> -1 AND rateFactor <> 0 AND bulkGlassCount = ''
```

They ALL must also be limited to "WHERE graphicsTeam = x AND ordercompletedate BETWEEN date1 AND date2"

Is there an easy way to do this? I attempted to have each one set in its own function but it not only takes an incredibly long time to load, it also doesn't work consistently. A lot of the limitations crossover but each one requires the different conditions for numbers to be accurate.

Comment: Which Database are you using ? Dynamic query is one way to do it.

Comment: What database are you using, how are you pulling the data and what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to get all of the results in a single table or make it easy to get individual results with the different conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in one query.  Something like this:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN bulkStartDate <> NULL THEN bulkFTS END) as bulkMODFTS,
       count(idOrder) as totalOrders
       count(case when rateFactor <> 0 AND smallFTS > 27 and bulkGlassCount = '' then idOrder end) as overFTS
      round(SUM(CASE WHEN rateFactor <> 0 AND THEN rateFactor END), 1) as totalFactors,
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN rateFactor <> 0 AND bulkGlassCount = '' THEN FTStime END), 2) as avgFTS
FROM cartHead
WHERE rateFactor <> -1 AND 
      graphicsTeam = x AND ordercompletedate BETWEEN date1 AND date2"
```